# Mustache template concatenation of expression with some string

Tags: javascript, string, polymer, mustache, ractivejs

How can we concatenate an expression value with some string and evaluate the resulting expression?

If we have one object prefix and I wanted to concatenate its value with some string. e.g

```
{{prefix"Output"}}
```

I would like to first evaluate the prefix value and then concatenate it with the "Output" string.

So the resulting expression may be something like "UnitOutput" where Unit is the value of the prefix.

Lastly I want the concatenated expression from above to be evaluated as well in that case resulting value will be the value of "UnitOutput".

Comment: I actually want to achieve something like this {{ {{prefix}}"Output" }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `prefix` did not work for me. I am assuming it is a reserved keyword. I will use `pref` in this example.

**Html**

```
<paper-input value="{{pref}}"></paper-input>
<span>Output: {{result}}</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
Polymer({
    pref: '',
    result: 'Output',
    prefChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
        this.result = newValue + 'Output';
        // evaluate result here
    }
}
```

Or you could use Polymers observer pattern

**Html**

```
<paper-input value="{{xyz.prefix}}"></paper-input>
<span>Output: {{result}}</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
Polymer({
    result: '',
    observe: {
        'xyz.prefix': 'validate'
    },
    validate: function(oldValue, newValue) {
        this.result = newValue + 'Output';
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.xyz = {
            prefix: 'test'
        }
    }
});
```

If you're observing Arrays please refer to [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js)

Comment: Its little complex, I have object xyz and prefix is its property. So prefix is not the main object which can be observed. Its a object within a object.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with Polymers observer pattern. I hope this will help you

Comment: Observer can work for the objects itself but I like to apply filter of one of its property.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code provided will result in exactly this `{{ {{prefix}}"Output" }}`. What else are you trying to achieve? Can you perhaps post some pseudo code in your question?

Comment: `observe: {
'xyz.y[0].Prefix': 'validate'
            },
            validate: function(oldValue, newValue) {
                alert("Prefix updated::"+newValue);
            }`

It's not working in my case.

Comment: I think [observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js) does exactly what you want. I have not yet used it so I can't guide you there. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You answer is correct but somehow it's not working on my end. Will try figure it out after the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

doing like

```
"{{variable}} Output"
```

should work

Comment: It can concatenate the resulting value but wanted to evaluate resulting expression as well. e.g {{ {{variable}}"Output"}} something like this

Comment: {{variable + "Output"}}? Read https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

With RactiveJS it's simply:

```
{{ this[prefix + "Output"] }}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/236bsky0/. `this` refers to current context or root, but can be another reference if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a function : {{ getValue(variable) }}
In your element, just declare your function : 
getValue: function(var) { return var + "Output";}